# How to use private repositories in your organization as Repositories to collaborate with Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-amplify

When you create Amplify, you specify a Repository, but if it is a private repository within your organization, you will get the error "There was an issue setting up your repository".
Is there any way to work around this?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-amplify-app.html

We are using GithubActions and Cloudformation to deploy to the Amplify console.

But it seems that authentication is required to access private repositories in the organization, so I can't link repositories.